# Ошибка при считывании файла с определенной структурой

Tags: c++, файлы, структуры

Считать файл, который содержит данные:

```
Vasilyeva, Ekateryna KNT-18-2: 5.
Bentley, Richie ITS-19-1: 3.
Anthony, Fesco SUR-9: 3.5.
Chadwick, Jaimee ET-20-21: 4.
Rogers, Britany WT-21-6: 2.
Vu, Marcelina CST-20-1: 4.5.
Lee, Elena CST-21-1: 3.5.
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему не считывает файл и выводит ошибку?

Код:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

/*
Read a text file that stores the following lines:
Last name, first name (space character) Group name: average score.
Display the group name if the name is "Elena" and the average score is more than 3,5.
*/

struct Students{
    char lastName[50];
    char firstName[50];
    char groupName[50];
    float averageScore;
};

int main() {
    fstream file("students.txt", ios::in);
    if (!file)
        cerr << "Error with opening file." << endl;
    else {
        cout << "The file was opened." << endl;

        // counting records
        char stop;
        int records = 0;
        for (file >> stop; !file.eof(); file >> stop)
            if (stop == '.') records++;
        file.close();

        // checking if there's records in file
        if (records == 0)
            cerr << "There's no records in file." << endl;
        else {
            fstream file("students.txt", ios::in);
            char line[256];
            Students* students = new Students[records];
            for (int i = 0; i < records; i++) {
                file.getline(line, 256, '.');

                // copying data from the file to structure
                strcpy(students[i].lastName, strtok(line, ","));
                strcpy(students[i].firstName, strtok(NULL, " "));
                strcpy(students[i].groupName, strtok(NULL, ":"));
                students[i].averageScore = atof(strtok(NULL, "."));

                // outputting data
                if (students[i].averageScore > 3.5 && students[i].averageScore <= 5.0
                    && strstr(students[i].firstName, "Elena"))
                    cout << students[i].groupName << endl;
            }
        }
    }
    file.close();
}
```

Comment: Пока вы не сказали, какую именно ошибку выводит — `3,5` в стандартной локали не является числом типа `float` — должно быть `3.5`...

Comment: Ошибка: Exception thrown at 0x7B1DF7B3 (ucrtbased.dll) in Exam.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.
Числа, где стояли запятые вместо точек для типа float, исправил, но всё так же не считывает.

Comment: А теперь у вас проблема с тем, что есть точки конечные и не конечные...